# Is there a way to make Prestashop's Layared Filter Module to use query parameters instead of anchors (hashes)?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, pushstate, html5-history

Is there any way to make the standart PrestaShop's Layered filters module to use URL parameters instead of anchors (the part after hash)?
I ment that I want the layered filter generate and accept the URLs like this *(or maybe somehow diferrent, but the key is to use parameters and not to use hashes)*:

```
my-example-shop.ru/some-category/?color=red&size=xl
```

instead of this:

```
my-example-shop.ru/some-category#/color-red/size-xl
```

The reason is that the most of advertisment systems could add some parameters to the URL, but they usuaul add it directly to the end of the URL, and dont trying to analyze url structure and insert parameters to the right place.

So, as far as i see, the obvious solution is to avoid using hashes in url, using just query parameters, and to use history.pushState to change URL without refreshing whole page...
It seems obvious, usable, but I cant find any ready-to-use solution that do this such way, and I cant find even information about how does someone did it..

So the questions are:

- is there any ready-to-use solution?
- is there any described way to reach this by myself?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD**

All I found by myself for now is that such URLs could be accepted:

```
my-example-shop.ru/some-category/color-red/size-xl
my-example-shop.ru/some-category?selected_filters=/color-red/size-xl
```

BUT any filters changing causes using hashes again (afaik, hashed filters values overrides values passed via selected_filters parameter, so subsequent navigation just ignores selected_filters). In other words - I just can clear the entry URL, BUT I couldnt make URLs to be clean for subsequent navigation.

Comment: you have to need customized for this. You can follow & modify the prestashop dispatcher class. `root/classes/Dispatcher.php` . Prestashop full url system are controlling by dispatcher. You can change the `layered_rule` from default routes.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not enough, because layered filter's behaviour is not just about routing, it's about parsing and manipulation the URLs in blocklayered.php and blocklayered.js, and the '#'-way seems to be deeply hardcoded...

Answer (score 0):

The change is very large.
You should create the override classes/Dispatcher.php

For filters instead you should edit the file: blocklayered/blocklayered.php
find function: getSelectedFilters()

Inside are two foreach, you should withdraw from the url "featured" fields that you need and compile the new array "$selected_filters"